# Cannot connect Ubuntu 18.04 to WIRED router / network

Tags: networking

Installed Ubuntu 18.04 as the only OS on Dell Optiplex 780 Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 / 3 GHz  NO WI-FI available on this machine.

Wired Ubuntu machine to a router with same Ethernet cable that 15 minutes ago successfully connected Win OS machine.

I entered router ID and password and triple checked it for correctness.

Ubuntu will not connect and keeps asking for password.

Manually input IP etc addresses (I obtained from the router with Windows machine) in Ubuntu settings.

Ubuntu will not connect and keeps asking for password.

While doing this restarted computer a couple of times. No success

I am not a geek and need some simple advice. If I need to get to command line you may need to tell me how to do it.